# mCustomScroll - Scrolling body focus on page load

Tags: jquery, mcustomscrollbar

I am using mCustomScrollbar's keyboard support which will let user scroll using arrow keys.

But user will be able to use the arrow keys once he has clicked the scrolling frame. My requirement is to let user scroll the scrolling frame on page load.

So basically what I want is to focus the scrolling frame after page has been loaded. I have tried applying .focus() once scrolling frame has been generated but it didn't worked.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Here is the code snippet : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XqxKWd

Here we can not scroll the div using arrow key unless we have clicked on the scrollable div. I want to focus the scrollable div on load so a user can use arrow keys to scroll div as soon as page has been loaded. @AlonEitan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried adding .focus() on #mCSB_1 and it will work.

```
(function($){
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".scrollBody").mCustomScrollbar({
       keyboard:{
         enable: true
       }
     });

     $('.scrollBody #mCSB_1').focus();

   })   
})(jQuery);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RyemBg